# Find non-matching characters from string1 and string2

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two long strings (5684400 characters each). They are *almost* the same: only a few characters are different.

I need to find what those characters are.

What is the fastest way to do so in PostgreSQL?

Comment: If you have two *strings*, why would you want to do this in a database?

Comment: 1minute googling: [Find difference between two Text fields](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4A6A75A5.4070203@intera.si)

Comment: @danihp tried that, but on a much bigger string. It was taking waaay to long :-(

Comment: @GordonLinoff in fact... makes sense! After all I'm just debugging something.

Answer (score 2):

That is not a task for a database server. However, if you do not want to transmit enormous strings from a remote server, install one of the available procedural languages, for example [Python](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython.html):

```
create or replace function diff_str(str1 text, str2 text)
returns setof text language plpython3u as $$
    res = []
    for i, c in enumerate(str1):
        if c != str2[i]:
            res += ('{}: {}->{}'.format(i+1, str1[i], str2[i]),)
    return res;
$$;

select * from diff_str('abcdefghijk', 'abcXefgYijk');

 diff_str 
----------
 4: d->X
 8: h->Y
(2 rows)
```

or [JavaScript (plv8)](https://github.com/plv8/plv8):

```
create or replace function diff_str_v8(str1 text, str2 text)
returns setof text language plv8 as $$
    for (var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++)
        if (str1[i] != str2[i])
            plv8.return_next(i+1+ ': '+ str1[i]+ '->'+ str2[i]);
$$;
```

The functions were tested on 12-million-character strings. Plv8 needed circa 0.2s, Python about 1.5s.

Answer (score 1):

A brute-force method is replace all matching cto turn the strings into a set and then use a full outer join and find only those that are different.

E.g. to compare `'Hello, world'` and `'Hello world.'` you could use

```
with s1(c) as (
  select * 
  from unnest(regexp_split_to_array('Hello, world', ''))
), s2 (c) as (
  select * 
  from unnest(regexp_split_to_array('Hello world.', ''))
)
select coalesce(s1.c, s2.c) as different
from s1
  full outer join s2 on s1.c = s2.c
where s1 is distinct from s2;
```

The above query returns:

```
different
---------
,        
.
```

If you need this for a one-time thing, this is probably good enough. But this is not going to scale well for a lot of strings.

Comment: but permutation on letters are not detected.  I guess on 5684400 they are all whole alphabet.